# The following deploy sub-keys are not supported in compatibility mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have to use a memory limit of 500MB and CPU set to 0.6 for a service and I also need to use version 3 in the docker-compose file.

I try:
`$ docker-compose docker_compose.yml --compatibility up`

and I get:

`WARNING: The following deploy sub-keys are not supported in compatibility mode and have been ignored: resources.reservations.cpus`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   web:
     image: myimage:1.2.3
     volumes:
       - 'delle:/home/rh'
     deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 500M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.6'
     networks:
       - mynetwork
       - internal

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
  internal:
volumes:
    delle:
```

Can somebody help? Swarm only?

Answer (score 1):

Might as well use v2 for [docker-compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources).

```yaml
version: "2.4"

services:
   web:
     image: myimage:1.2.3
     volumes:
       - 'delle:/home/rh'
     cpu_count: 1
     cpus: 0.6
     cpu_percent: 30
     mem_limit: 500m
     networks:
       - mynetwork
       - internal

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
  internal:
volumes:
    delle
```

For v3, this explains why it doesn't support `resources.reservations.cpus` and `resources.limits.cpus` as memory. See [thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5684#issuecomment-409206672)

> Docker Compose doesn't work with swarm mode (it deploys local containers), so there's no orchestrator to take those limits into account

as @Kalpesh pointed out (*below my comment*), try removing **resources, reservations cpus**.

you could inspect it via:

```sh
# run compatibility
docker-compose --compatibility up -d

docker inspect --format '{{json .HostConfig.Memory}}' <CONTAINER_NAME> | numfmt --to=iec

docker inspect --format '{{json .HostConfig.NanoCpus}}' <CONTAINER_NAME> | numfmt --to=iec
```